# Возврат кода 500 от скрипта на Debian10 \ Apache2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, веб-программирование, apache2

Сайт на OpenServer и веб-хостинге работал идеально, переехал на дедик и впервичной настройке столкнулся с тем, что некоторый функционал сайта не работает.

1. Не загружается один из скриптов ajax.php (donators)
2. Не работает мобильная верстка на телефоне

F12 Отдает такой ответ:
https://sun9-70.userapi.com/im... type=album

Не понимаю куда копать, много туториалов уже перебрал.

Лог из error.log https://paste.ee/p/m2nk2
интересует еще так же этот момент:
это access.log, на один скрипт он отвечает удачно, на второй ошибкой 500.

Comment: Если syntax error, значит вероятно ваш php-код несовместим с используемой вами версией php

Comment: Ну а что значит «не работает мобильная верстка» и при чём тут дедик просто непонятно

Comment: @andreymal, я не знаю в чем проблема, потому описал все в общих чертах как я это вижу.
Если понадобится какая-то информация, просто дай знать и я опишу ее.
Не работает мобильная вертска, означает, что при заходе на сайт с мобильного там нет никакого дизайна, обычные кнопки, без всяких форм и цвета.
На вебстранице с ПК - все хорошо, но не работает лишь один элемент (на скриншоте его указал)

в OpenServer указывал такой же php как и у меня на дедике.
На дедике такой проблемы нет, там все работает как нужно.

Comment: Если нет дизайна, значит видимо не загрузились стили, а почему не загрузились стили, смотрите уже в мониторинге сети браузера и соответствующих логах сервера

Comment: А скриншота здесь никакого нет

Comment: @andreymal, видимо обрезало.
https://sun9-70.userapi.com/impf/HueaoxBlkGsuSLpcvtXHB_3Jh1oTBJlUuu0IPA/kBsmInJpNW0.jpg?size=1920x120&quality=96&sign=7ac882c42c9293dc4127698de29e5e71&type=album

в какие логи сервера смотреть?

Comment: так же про несовместимость, прошлый хостинг предоставлял PHP 7.2, сейчас 7.3
на OpenServer ставлю и ту, и ту версию - сайт загружает нормально в обоих вариантах.
Вдобавок к этому, я проверил на каком-то сайте-анализаторе и там тоже написали что код совместим.
Я конечно постараюсь поиграться с php версией, но сайт везде удачно работал.. не думаю, что рпоблема в этом. хотя спасибо

Comment: Ну значит дальше гадать не получится и нужно конкретно смотреть, что же там в строке 17 расположено

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/8zN0MDN_UbJ6fw
Пробел, убрав его - проблема не исчезает.

Comment: Значит ошибка где-то в одной из предыдущих строк, а гадать по скриншотам мы не умеем, особенно по мелким и обрезанным

Comment: В вашем файле применяются короткие теги `<?` `?>`, вы не забыли включить их в настройках php?

Comment: вопрос решен, спасибо.
включение коротких тегов помогло.